# Delete ALL duplicate values in openoffice calc

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a list that is updated daily via google docs. I then copy the data and special paste the values only, so when the list is updated I have the previous day's data already saved.

I want to find only the new data that was added to the list. So what I did was copy and paste special the new list into the same column as the previous day's list. Then I moved everything into openoffice and did a standard filter for removing duplicates. However, this did not let me find the new data, it just deleted any extraneous duplicate data. Any ideas on how to just filter for the new values?

Answer (score 1):

For both Calc and Excel the quick and dirty solution would be

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A;$A1)
```

copied down for every entry in Column A.

All entries where the result is 1 can be filtered as new values.

Calc syntax for COUNTIF: http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_COUNTIF_function